# How to scale WPS office application?

Tags: 17.10, scaling, wps-office

I have installed WPS Office. But the icons in the application do not seem to scale up to fit my screen resolution.

How do I fix this? I have tried adding --force-device-scale-factor=1.5 in the .desktop files after the Exec line. But this does not work.

Thanks for all help in advance!